# function to create an array from a string in C without strtok

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, c-strings

Given a string "red, yellow, blue, green" I need to write a function that creates an array with the colors as the elements.  I'm having trouble finding information on this problem because I'm not allowed to use strtok or any string manipulation functions from string.h. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
int findLength(char string[]){
    int l =0;

    for(l = 0; string[l]!='\0'; l++){

    }
    return l;
};


char *stringToArray(char string[]){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char c = ',';
    int n = 0;
    int l = findLength(string);

    char *str = (char *)malloc(l * sizeof(char));

    while(string[i] != '\0'){
        if(string[i] == c){
            for(n = j; n < i; n++){
                str[j++] += string[n];
            }

        }
        i++;
    }
    printf("%s\n", str);
    str = '\0';
    return str;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *string = "red, blue, green,";
    char *str = stringToArray(string);
    free(str);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you have a specfic problem following [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35756596/how-to-create-a-string-from-an-array-of-strings-c)?

Comment: what's your code so far?

Comment: @bruceg i just updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through your string like this after you find your string's length:

```
for(int i=1; i<size; ++i)
```

And then you check if the current character is a letter and the previous is a space:

```
if(string[i] >= 97 && string[i] <= 122 && string[i-1] == ' ') //assuming your string has only lower case letters
```

Then you should implement a while loop that loops until it finds another space or comma and place everything in your new array.

Remember that your first word is a special case because it doesn't have any spaces before it.

Comment: `string.length`? And please use `'a'` and `'z'` instead of magic numbers.

Comment: You're right I forgot he isn't supposed to use string related methods. I'll change that now.

Comment: It would be better to remember the previous char than use the dangerous `string[i-1]`, then the first word need not be a "special case".

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the string until you find a comma.  Then copy everything from the start to that point into a separate string in an array.

Continue to iterate until you find another comma, then copy everything from where you left off until where you are now into another string in the array.

Repeat until you have reached the end of the string.  Also, be sure to skip over any spaces after you find each comma.

Answer (score 0):

> [..] an array with the colors as the elements [..]

This is going to be an array of arrays of characters. Or, since you don't know the sizes of neither the array of arrays nor of the individual arrays, you use pointers:

```
char ** parts; // a pointer to a(n array of) pointer(s) to a(n array of) char(s)
```

You need to allocate some space for the first element of `parts`:

```
parts = malloc(sizeof(*parts) * 1); // Space for one pointer, to start with
```

Now, you iterate over your input string (string = pointer to an array of chars, the last char having the value `'\0'`) with some pointer (`point`). Remember a start position (using a pointer `start`) one position *before* the first character of your input string.
When, during iteration, you find one of your separation characters (`','` for example), then count the number of characters between the `start` and `point` pointers. If it's greater than 0, then allocate memory for that number + 1 characters and assign the resulting pointer to the last element of `parts`:

```
// example for the first iteration, you need to change that 0
parts[0] = malloc(numberOfCharacters + 1);
```

Finally, copy everything between `start` and `point` into that newly allocated memory. `strncpy` will be helpful here (if you're not allowed to use it, then write yourself a replacement. Do **not** put that logic in your tokenizing function).

Set the `start` to `point`.

If you're not at the end of your input, get more space to store more pointers in `parts`: This can be done using `realloc`. Then go back to iterating until you find one of your separation characters (or the end of the string).

Be sure to check **every** (re)allocation. Read the entries for above functions *carefully* in a reference of your choice (example: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c ).